# iOS: How do I set a view's background color to be the same as UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, uiview, background-color

I have some views that slide up and down at the bottom of the screen, and I would like them to be the same color as the UINavigationBar. Is there some easy way to do this, like the textured look you get from `[UIColor underPageBackgroundColor]`?  (And no, I do not want to use `UIToolbar`)

Comment: Are you saying you want to match the same blue gradient but spread across 480 pixels vertically?

Comment: No I want to match the same blue gradient over a smaller view at the bottom of the screen, similar to UIToolbar, but using UIView.

Comment: There's no magic bullet here as it's not an included color in `UIColor`. Your choices are to attempt to recreate it in an image editor or create an image from a blank `UINavigationBar` using CoreGraphics.

Comment: Hmm... that's unfortunate. Copy that as an answer and I'll accept.